# Converting character string to datetime with strftime

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert a string representation of a datetime using the strftime function, but the results are not what I'm expecting.

```
str_dtime <- "1/2/2007 00:00:00"
strftime(str_dtime, format = "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S")
```

The value returned in this example is

`"20/02/0001 12:00:00"`

I'm new to R and am not sure what is wrong here.  It looks like my format settings match up, so I'm not sure if there is something else going on?

Comment: `strptime(str_dtime, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")` works for me where I replaced `%I` by `%H` and use `strptime` instead (not sure what is the difference)

Comment: `strftime` dose not convert strings to datetimes; that's what `strptime` is for.  `strftime` converts datetimes to strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two issues. First, `strftime` **f**ormats a datetime object to a string. `strptime` converts a string to a datetime object.  Second, the `"%I"` format only accepts values between 01-12, which does not include 00, as in your example.  So you probably need to use `"%H"` instead.

```
R> strptime(str_dtime, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2007-02-01 CST"
```

Also note that the R convention does not print `"H:M:S"` for midnight.